# How to fix cannot resolve "CELL_TYPE_BLANK"?

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a xlsx file in my app. I'm using Apache POI 4.0.1. I'm getting an error:

> cannot resolve symbol CELL_TYPE_BLANK"

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constant you're using no longer exists. From the Apache POI 3.17 Javadoc of [`Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/3.17/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#CELL_TYPE_BLANK):

> ### CELL_TYPE_BLANK
>
> ```
> @Deprecated
> @Removal(version="4.0")
> static final int CELL_TYPE_BLANK
> ```
>
> **Deprecated.** *POI 3.15 beta 3. Use [CellType.BLANK](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/3.17/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html#BLANK) instead.*
>   Blank Cell type (3)

As indicated by `@Removal(version="4.0")`, it was scheduled to be removed in POI 4 and it has been removed. You need to use `CellType.BLANK` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much.u gave me answer in a single word.

Answer (score 0):

Using POI **v4.0.1**

Instead of

```
myCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK
```

use

```
myCell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK
```